# Asignacion de evento onClick usando document.getElementById

Tags: javascript, html

### Codigo

```js
function asignarEventos() {

  var uno = document.getElementById("uno");
  var dos = document.getElementById("dos");
  var tres = document.getElementById("tres");

  var arreglo = [uno, dos, tres];

  for (var i = 0; i < arreglo.length; i++) {

    var elemento = arreglo[i];
    var texto = elemento.innerHTML.trim();

    elemento.onclick = function(){
      alert(texto);
    };

  }

}

asignarEventos();
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>

  <a id="uno">
    Uno
  </a>

  <a id="dos">
    Dos
  </a>

  <a id="tres">
    Tres
  </a>

</body>

</html>
```

---

### Objetivo

La variable `arreglo` contiene un listado de elementos HTML, que se obtienen previamente usando `document.getElementById()`. Posteriormente quiero asignar de una manera dinamica un evento al elemento HTML usando la propiedad `.onclick` de los DOM Element.

*Lo que quiero es que al dar click sobre alguno de los elementos `<a>`, se muestre un `alert()` o bien se ejecute una funcion mostrando el texto contenido en ellos.*

---

### Problema

En esta seccion del codigo:

```
var elemento = arreglo[i];
var texto = elemento.innerHTML.trim();

elemento.onclick = function(){
  alert(texto);
};
```

Obtengo el elemento contenido en la variable `arreglo`, y posteriormente obtengo su valor `innerHTML`, es decir, el texto que el contiene, luego asigno el atributo `onclick` asignando una funcion anonima que ejecutara un `alert()` mostrando el texto que contiene el elemento HTML.

Pero al hacer click sobre cualquiera de los elementos siempre se imprime el `innerHTML` del ultimo de los elementos, en este caso es la palabra "tres". Cuando deberia ser el valor de cada elemento individualmente.

---

### Pregunta

*Como se puede asignar un evento `onClick()` a un elemento obtenido con `document.getElementById()` ?*

---

### Nota

> Cabe aclarar que el problema lo debo **solucionar usando JavaScript puro**, no me sirve usar una libreria como jQuery u otros, ya que en dicho entorno no puedo hacer uso de ella.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

El problema ocurre por problemas de ámbito/scope. Recuerda:

> Una variable declarada con `var` siempre tiene un scope de función o un scope global. Toda variable declarada dentro de una función, sea o no dentro de un bloque o estructura, siempre aplica a [hoisting](https://scotch.io/tutorials/understanding-hoisting-in-javascript).

**Ejemplo hosting**

```js
// ES5
(function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    var x = i;
  }
  console.log(x);
})();

// ES6
(() => {
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    let y = i;
  }
  console.log(y); // error
})();
```

Como puedes darte cuenta, en el primer ejemplo, `x` sigue estando disponible aún fuera del loop for, esto sucede porque las variables ES5 sufren un proceso distinto cuando son declaradas; esto no sucede en ES6 con `let` y `const`.

En tu código, la variable `texto`, al ser de ámbito de función, **siempre guarda la última referencia que se le asigne**, es decir, el texto del último elemento del arreglo. Lo que debes hacer es usar un [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) o usar `let` o `const`.

```js
function asignarEventos() {
  var arreglo = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('a[id]'));

  for (var i = 0; i < arreglo.length; i++) {
    var elemento = arreglo[i];
    const texto = elemento.innerHTML.trim();
    elemento.onclick = function() {
      alert(texto);
    };
  }
}

asignarEventos();
```

```html
<body>
  <a id="uno">
    Uno
  </a>
  <a id="dos">
    Dos
  </a>
  <a id="tres">
    Tres
  </a>
</body>
```

Answer (score 6):

Por cada iteracion que hace el `for` se escribe el valor de la variable `texto`. Intenta accediendo al elemento en si con `this` y asi leer el contenido:

```js
function asignarEventos() {

  var uno = document.getElementById("uno");
  var dos = document.getElementById("dos");
  var tres = document.getElementById("tres");

  var arreglo = [uno, dos, tres];

  for (var i = 0; i < arreglo.length; i++) {

    var elemento = arreglo[i];
    
    elemento.onclick = function(){
      alert(this.innerHTML.trim());
    };

  }

}

asignarEventos();
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>

  <a id="uno">
    Uno
  </a>

  <a id="dos">
    Dos
  </a>

  <a id="tres">
    Tres
  </a>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Si me permites la sugerencia, quita la linea `var texto = elemento.innerHTML.trim();`. Muy buena respuesta. Es la misma que estaba preparando, pero te me adelantaste :-)

Comment: Podrías simplificar el código si usases `var arreglo = document.querySelectorAll("#uno, #dos, #tres")` o también quitando la asignación de `elemento` para hacer `onclick` (o `addEventListener`) directamente a `arreglo[i]`

Answer (score 4):

#### Utilizando un [Closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures):

```js
function asignarEventos() {

  var uno = document.getElementById("uno");
  var dos = document.getElementById("dos");
  var tres = document.getElementById("tres");

  var arreglo = [uno, dos, tres];

  for (var i = 0; i < arreglo.length; i++) {

  var elemento = arreglo[i];

  elemento.onclick = function(elem){
 return function(){
    alert(elem.innerHTML.trim());
 }
  }(elemento);

  }

}

asignarEventos();
```

```html
<html>

<body load="">

  <a id="uno">
Uno
  </a>

  <a id="dos">
Dos
  </a>

  <a id="tres">
Tres
  </a>

</body>

</html>
```

#### ¿ Por qué no funciona el código original ?

La funcion que has definido para el evento `onClick` lee el valor de la variable externa `texto` en tiempo de ejecucion, en lugar de copiar su valor cuando la función es definida. Cualquier modificacion ulterior de la variable externa afecta la ejecucion de la función.

Answer (score 3):

Prueba mostrar el texto con un `this` así:

```
...

for (var i = 0; i < arreglo.length; i++) {

    var elemento = arreglo[i];

    elemento.onclick = function(){
      alert(this.innerHTML.trim());
    };

  }
```